# ssh automation deploy user www-data or other user

Tags: linux, ssh, automation, deployment

We have our project on `/var/www` and it is owned by user `www-data`.

I would like to create an automation for deploy so I do:

- Connect through SSH as user `www-data`
- Navigate to `/var/www/somefolder`
- Perform `git pull` and all the relevant stuff.

Is it secure to log in with `www-data` through ssh and perform these actions?

Or should I log in with a different user and then give him `www-data` group? Or log in with different user and then `su www-data` and than do the work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use `Shift` a bit more than just for *"OR"*. You could also improve question's title and use some [formatting](https://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this isn't so much that it is insecure to log in as `www-data` but that it is insecure to have your entire website writable by that account. You should use another account for managing your website files which has write permissions to the directories. That user should own the files (and is generally also in the `www-data` group but this isn't absolutely needed). You will then be able to set the permissions you need by using the group permissions to specify what the website can do and user permissions to specify what your management account can do. You probably won't ever need to give any permissions to `others` for these files.

This management account should also be able to `sudo chmod` (and probably `sudo chown`) those files as needed in order to allow the website write permissions on specific folders in your site (such as a temp folder). If you do not want to allow that by this user then you'll need to provide folders for this purpose that you require website managers to use.

Edit: You can also remove read permission on files to remove them from the website without deleting them. This is a little less safe to do though because you may accidentally set it back without knowing when you upload it next time. This is why I would also suggest always writing a publish script to automate uploading your files and doing these sort of changes so they are never forgotten.

Comment: so www-data will only have read permission on all the files (except those he writes in to or folders where it saves uploads) and the other user will have full access to all the files. all the files would be owned by that user, and in group www-data

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem, we have to make sure all have www-data permissions. I solved my problem by using these commands.

```bash
sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/
```